# Multiple Spacebar Conditional Operators

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze, spacebars

Is there a way to shorten

```
{{#if arg1}}
    {{#if arg2}}
        //stuff
    {{/if}}
{{/if}}
```

to just a single if?

```
{{#if arg1 arg2}}
{{#if arg1 && arg2}}
```

Both of the above don't seem to work.

Comment: I discovered I can use UI.registerHelper(), however I am unsure how to configure this to take in any number of arguements. (Arrays do not seem to work, have yet to try maps)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Spacebars continues the philosophy of Mustache and Handlebars being logic-less template languages. This is why even simple logic is best placed in the controller rather than in the template.

You can, however, [define a custom block helper](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/spacebars/README.md#custom-block-helpers) that performs a logical `and`.

```
<template name="ifand">
  {{#if arg1}}
    {{#if arg2}}
      {{> Template.contentBlock}}
    {{else}}
      {{> Template.elseBlock}}
    {{/if}}
  {{else}}
    {{> Template.elseBlock}}
  {{/if}}
</template>
```

Call as:

```
{{#ifand arg1="foo" arg2="bar"}}
  // stuff
{{/ifand}}
```

You can also learn [more about passing variables into templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10128053/is-there-a-way-to-pass-variables-into-templates-in-meteor/25090098#25090098).

For the general case (`and` among an arbitrary number of arguments), you'll want to register a global template helper:

```
Template.registerHelper('and', function () {
  var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0, -1);  // exclude key=value args
  var parameters = arguments[arguments.length - 1];  // key: value arguments

  return _.every(args, function (arg) {
    return !!arg;
  });

});
```

Call as:

```
{{#if and 1 "foo" 3 'bar' param="test"}}
  True
{{else}}
  False
{{/if}}
```

Comment: I know how to pass variables into templates, what worries me about this approach is it isn't capable of handling X arguements. I need a number of different templates to perform essentially the same task. Being able to define my own helpers feels like the correct route to go, but I do not understand how passing variables into the helper works, unless it has the same problem of only being able to handle a single variable.

Comment: Can you not define Template successfully in the lib folder? If not, where is the best place to put global Template helper definitions?

Comment: I'd put them in `/client/lib`. `Template` should be defined there.

Comment: That's a good idea. I'll make a note of that for my standards. Thanks for all your help good sir.

Answer (score 1):

While within a template, you are able to use the **this** object to reference arguments passed in, which lets me avoid having to use multiple #if arguements in most of the cases I need them in.

```
Template.myTemplate.created = function() {
    if(this.data.arg1 && this.data.arg2) {
        //do JS setup here
    }
}
```

Additionally, helpers can be specified using

```
Template.registerHelper('exists', function() {
    if(this.data.arg1 && this.data.arg2) {
        return true
    }
}
```

and you execute the above helper as such

```
{{#if exists}}
    //stuff
{{/if}}

{{> myTemplate arg1 arg2}}
```

I just stumbled on this by accident but this is a HUGE find for me.

Comment: I believe [UI.registerHelper is, being deprecated](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/3017). Please check my updated answer.

Comment: I tried using Template.registerHelper, and it kept telling me that Template was undefined. This is odd. If this is the case, I need to figure out why it isn't working for me and update this accordingly.

Comment: Updated this to reflect your information so I don't spread information. Please see my comment on your answer though, as UI exists during lib definition but Template does not and I feel like lib is where I should be defining my global helpers.

Comment: I tried this out and it didn't work for me.  I didn't even see a data property off of the .this context.  I tried this for example {{> myTemplate "country" "label for country" "true" "another string with spaces" true}}.  Then Template.registerHelper('exists', function ([no parameters?]) { if (this.data.arg1) { return true } });  There is not this.data, what is the arg1 in my case?  How do I refer to "country" for example?  I looked at the locals in debug, there is no "country".  Thanks for this tip by the way. I hope it works as I usually have to build a dummy helper that's just a pass-through

Comment: I don't know what .data isn't being exposed to you (and I assume is why there are no args in that function call, because you reference the args through .data).

Are you using Meteor 1.0X?