# Passing values from an array to child template in meteor

Tags: arrays, templates, meteor, static, nested

I've been grappling with the following problem:

I have two templates:

```
intervalsList
intervalIcon
```

I want `intervalsList` to populate with a list of `intervalIcons`.

Each `intervalIcon` displays a number; there is an array of these numbers:

```
[1, 5, 10, 15, 30, 45, 60]
```

The `intervalsList` template iterates through this array, instantiating an `intervalIcon` for each index:

```
{{#each interval}}
    {{> intervalIcon}}  
{{/each}}
```

`interval` is defined as an array, as a helper of `intervalsList`:

```
Template.intervalsList.helpers({
    'interval': [1, 5, 10, 15, 30, 45, 60]
});
```

This works. A number of intervals are instantiated that corresponds with the size of the array.

However, I still need to display the number from each index of the array within an interval. (For instance, within a list item.)

e.g.

Array `[1, 5, 10, 15, 30, 45, 60]` outputs:

- 1
- 5
- 10
- 15
- 30
- 45
- 60

I've tried the following:

```
<template name="intervalsList">
  {{#each interval}}
    {{> intervalIcon data={{this}} }}
  {{/each}}
</template>
```

Which at runtime is not accepted:

```
    While building the application:
client\views\settingsGeneral\settingsGeneral.html:18: Expected identifier, number, string, boolean, or null
...{> intervalIcon data={{this}}}}  
    {{/eac...
                        ^
```

I'm using two templates instead of one because the second template (`intervalIcon`) contains a Chart.js chart, which is complicated enough that I'd like to keep it separate from the first template.

How can I pass the value from the `interval` array retrieved during `intervalList`'s `#each` loop to a sub-template, so that I can use it there?

I've looked at this question: [Is there a way to pass variables into templates in Meteor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10128053/is-there-a-way-to-pass-variables-into-templates-in-meteor) 
It mentions something about using `../` to reference a nested template's parent's data context, but I didn't really understand it.

Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to explicitly pass the currently iterated over item to the child template, it is automatically done by `Spacebars`.

Inside your `intervalIcon` template, you can refer to the item value using `{{this}}`.

```
<template name="intervalIcon">
  <p>{{this}}</p>
</template>
```

You can also give the interval value a name by replacing your array values by objects :

JS

```
Template.intervalsList.helpers({
  interval: function(){
    return [1, 5, 10, 15, 30, 45, 60].map(function(value){
      return {
        value: value
      };
    });
  }
});
```

HTML

```
<template name="intervalIcon">
  <p>{{value}}</p>
</template>
```

Comment: Thanks so much!! That was a really fast response.