# Passing arguments to a Blaze template

Tags: javascript, html, templates, meteor, meteor-blaze

Say I have a common piece of markup that will be repeated throughout my website with only a few small differences.

For example, I have a bunch of `<div>` elements that all have a title.

Elements with class: `section-title` are all styled the same way, but their text content is different.

I would like to make a template to represent a title, sort of like this:

```
<template name="section-title">
  <div class="section-title">
    <span> Profile </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Except, I need "Profile" to be interchangeable, because I have many different sections: "profile", "contact information", etc.

What is the best way to do this in Blaze?

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10128053/is-there-a-way-to-pass-variables-into-templates-in-meteor?rq=1  Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use either template arguments or set the template current data context to the appropriate list of arguments.

HTML

```
<template name="sectionTitle">
  <section class="section-title">
    <span>{{title}}</span>
  </section>
</template>

{{> sectionTitle title="Profile"}}

<template name="parent">
  {{> sectionTitle args}}
</template>
```

JS

```
Template.parent.helpers({
  args: function(){
    return {
      title: "Profile"
    };
  }
});
```