# Passing variable from parent template to child template in meteor

Tags: templates, meteor

I have a parent template with several nested child templates inside it. And inside each nested template I have a string generated from an array. A simplified model of my html:

```
<template name="parent">
   <a class="logId">Console log parent Id</a>
   {{> firstChild}}
   {{> secondChild}}
</template>
```

In addition my child templates have an each loop like this:

```
<template name="firstChild">
   {{#each users}}
      {{this}}
      {{> adminSelectUser}}
   {{/each}}
</template>

<template name="adminSelectUser">
   <a class="selectUser">SelectUser</a>
</template>
```

In my js code:

```
Template.parent.events({
    'click .logId': function () {
       var eventId = this._id._str;
       console.log(eventId);
});

Template.adminSelectUser.events({
   'click .selectUser': function(template){
      var userString = this.valueOf();
      console.log(userString);
    }
 });
```

To this point I get it to work and in both of my templates I can find the id of my parent and the string of my user as I want it to do. But then I would also want to use both my variables eventId and userString in the same method call, called from the template adminSelectUser. Is there any way that I can pass the eventId found in the parent template down to the adminSelectUser template so that I can work with both variables with the same method call.

This is what I aim to do with my server methods:

```
Meteor.methods({
    removeUser: function(){
       Meets.update({_id: eventId}, {$pull : {usersApplied: userString}});
  }
});
```

I want my server method to recognize the eventId and the userString and get them to work together when I call the method later on in the adminSelectUser template.

Hope this is clear enough!

Comment: see similar question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10128053/is-there-a-way-to-pass-variables-into-templates-in-meteor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to go about this.

1. Using `Template.parentData`

   You can traverse the template hierarchy from within template JS using `Template.parentData(n)` where `n` is the number of levels up in the hierarchy you want to go.  So specifically for your example:

   ```
   Template.adminSelectUser.events({
     'click .selectUser': function(template){
       var user = this;
       var parentId = Template.parentData(2)._id;

       myRemoveMethod(parentId, user);
     }
   });
   ```

   However, this means that the inner template relies on *always* being rendered within the same hierarchy, which kinda has a bad smell.  If the templates are tightly coupled and this is the case (which is likely) then using `parentData` is probably fine.  However, if a template has data dependencies it does make sense to pass the appropriate data explicitly (see #2).
2. Pass the data into the templates explicitly.

   ```
   <template name="firstChild">
     {{#each users}}
       {{this}}
       {{> adminSelectUser user=this parent=..}}
     {{/each}}
   </template>
   ```

   In your example, when you pass no argument to a template render, the data context is assumed to be `this`.  Here instead we pass a `user` and a `parent` into the template (Note the use of `..` here to reference `this` outside of the users loop).  Your handler would then look more like:

   ```
   Template.adminSelectUser.events({
     'click .selectUser': function() {
       var data = Template.currentData();
       myRemoveMethod(data.parent._id, data.user);
     }
   });
   ```